# Is it safe to have 1 letter class names in PHP, e.g A, B, C

Tags: php

Is it safe to have single letter class names like A, B, P, etc?

Comment: Single letter class names are *boring*. Here is where it gets interesting: `class Ü {  }`... In theory, even a class named with the Unicode `HOT BEVERAGE` character is possible: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2615/index.htm  It works in PHP 5.3, but unfortunately, no programming font seems to support it. :)

Comment: Sure it can? I thought that apart from alphanumeric + `_` only `\x7f-\xff` were allowed? And hot beverage is above that, I think.

Comment: Strange! `class ☂ {  }` works on PHP 5.3. (For those missing the right font, that is `\ux2602 UMBRELLA`

Comment: @nikic yeah, I thought that too! Strange.

Comment: Someone ought to tell them they update the documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php, if PHP 5.3 really allowes that cool kind of stuff.

Comment: @nikic I can't say for 100% certain yet. It could be that the umbrella and the hot beverage get somehow transliterated by my IDE (it shows a box instead). Interesting, I'll take a look into it (or maybe ask a question) when I get around to it.

Comment: `function ÜÄÖß京警谨鲸Αυτουрусски() { return 1; }` works in PHP

Comment: @Gordon Just joking around :) Although if `UMBRELLA` works, it will become an easter egg in one of my apps. `$umbrella = new ☂();` is too good *not* to do. Or `☠();` (`SKULL AND CROSSBONES`) as a synonym for `unset()`. The *possibilities!*

Comment: Actually, I'd use ☠(); for die(); and OMG it works #lol

Comment: And I'm gonna `define('π', pi());`

Comment: I don't get why this works. Zend defines `{LABEL}` still same as in docs. But maybe I simply don't get all this yy stuff.

Comment: @nikic apparently, the entire unicode range works `define('␀', NULL);` although the manual clearly says, it should be `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`

Comment: Yes, and not only the manual says so, the code says so, too! I simply don't get it :(

Comment: @nikic @Pekka made a question out of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417180/unicode-class-names-bug-or-feature

Comment: So what will the server admin think when he see's a file named ☠ for the class?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### No.

Your future self *will* build a time machine for the sole purpose of slapping you for writing such unreadable code.  And then, a paradox will result, and **all of reality as we know it will be destroyed**.

Answer (score 11):

Why should it be unsafe? You may use them, if you want. It only is discouraged, because single char class names aren't very descriptive...

Maybe you want to give the class a normal name but let the user import it with a short alias?

```
use Some\Long\But\Descriptive\Classname as A;
```

Answer (score 4):

Safe, yes. Readable, no.

Comment: In other words, `safe != smart`

Answer (score 4):

It's interpreter-safe.  But it may not keep you "safe" from fellow programmers who have to support it :)

Out of curiosity, what would be the compelling reason for that?  I assume there must be one.

Comment: They are representing html tags such as `<b>`, `<p>`, etc

Comment: Or BoldElement, ParagraphElement, etc.  Maybe shorten them a bit, but the HTML tags themselves represent something to which the class names can be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why it shouldn't be, but it's more useful to give your classes a meaningful name

EDIT

Link to [PHP naming guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is nothing stopping you except for the confusion factor.

Answer (score 1):

only safe if it's a class that communicates with no other by the same name