# looking for code which validate javascript variable name

Tags: php, validation

I need to get some javascript variable names from user. And user can enter only valid variable names. For instance:

```
"test1" - valid input,
"test 1" - not valid input.
"_a" - valid.
```

Now I am looking for php code which can validate user input with javascript variable naming standards.

Comment: have you tied regex?

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service. You need to make an attempt to solve the issue yourself first. If you already have tried something, please share your code and explain where it goes wrong.

Comment: "Looking for code" is not an appropriate question. Please read [ask].

Comment: Actually, I can use regex and check if input has character except numbers (after first), and _. And if it has - then is not valid input. But I hope to find more clarified code.

Comment: look at https://mothereff.in/js-variables , this may help

Comment: I need to see your full code. Anyway, the logic is to get user input(Post or Get method, what you used) and then with regex check the variable. I repeat, I need more code to help.

Comment: _"But I hope to find more clarified code"_ - As mentioned, if you have code, show us and let us know where it fails. If not, the question is off topic.

Comment: Related theme https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980154/how-to-check-if-a-string-can-be-used-as-a-variable-name-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you are not expecting any unicode values, here is a regex you can try:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*$/', $jsVar, $matches)){
     var_dump($matches);
}
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kkaITE/1), [PHP Demo](https://eval.in/898686)