# Calling a class method with some special character on it (spanish here) sometimes fails and sometimes works

Tags: php, oop

Well, we have **PHP 5.2.15** on our servers and we really like our language so some methods have this **ñ**, and the really akward thing is that sometimes our code fails, throwing a **call to undifned method** fatal error (totally random in time).

We've tested a lot and still don't have a clue on this. I hope some of you know something.

Comment: I can't see how this can be answered in any meaningful way. You will have to add *some* relevant information (like the exact error message and line number and what can be found in that line number).

Comment: Have you tried using the ASCII equivalent of the N tilde?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the developers post-poned (maybe even cancelled) built-in unicode support, which had been planned for PHP6.  It would have allowed you to use unicode characters in your class/function/method/var names.

<s>For now, your only option is to use plain ascii characters.</s>

Comment: Incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417180/exotic-names-for-methods-constants-variables-and-fields-bug-or-feature

Comment: Edited for correctness.  However, after reading the accepted answer to your question, my opinion is that using multibyte characters (in class/function/method names) is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: definitely. It's also a pain to maintain for users that are not used to write non-ascii chars.