# CI how risky is to leaving CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters empty?

Tags: php, codeigniter

There are already some posts about disallowed key characters but this one has different question. I want to know how risky is if I leave `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` empty. What can happen? 
The reason? I need to have `enable_query_strings FALSE` and I use Arabic words in

URL:

```
www.mydomain.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A`
```

I never rely on value from URL, I always do some cleaning before. But I am not sure how Codeigniter handles routes and how it includes files. Do they rely on this single permitted_uri_chars rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you want to include only Arabic characters you can include unicode ranges in premitted_uri_chars regexp. Using [this wikipedia site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) we can try to construct regexp:</strike>

```
a-z 0-9~%.:_\- \x0600-\x06FF
```

Unfortunately for our case CodeIgniter doesn't use the `u` modifier (used for unicode) in `preg_match`. So in order for this to work you would need to modify source code file [system/core/URI.php, line 257](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/URI.php#L257) line, and change it to:

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|iu", $str))
```

In the above code I've added only the `u` modifier to `preg_match`. Alternatively you can extend `URI` class as desribed in [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html), which is a better choice.

(I didn't test this)

To answer the question why it is bad to allow all characters: I can only think of SQL Injection problems or [other kinds of injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Resource_Injection).

Edit: for example if you use url `index.php/main/get_pdf?filename=awesome.pdf` to download pdf files from `./pdf/awesome.pdf` if you don't treat (i.e. validate) your input correctly malicious user could do something like this: `index.php/main/get_pdf?filename=../secure_files/nuclear_launch_codes.pdf` ;).

Edit2: Well, above example is a not an example of bad use of `permitted_uri_chars` because AFAIK CodeIgniter allows this kind of url variables, so you need to validate this stuff your self. I'll check all of this stuff when I get home.

Edit3: I fixed regexp, but it seems that this is not the way to enable Arabic characters so I crossed out this part of the answer.

I played with CodeIgniter a little. I don't know if this stuff will work on other system. It works on my Windows XP, PHP 5.3. This is what I found:

- In PHP you can use UTF-8 characters as function and class identifiers, but it is not officialy supported (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5358824/1637178) for further info).
- In CodeIgniter the `controller/method` part of the URL is url encoded (e.g. `ـج‎‎` is converted to `%D9%80%D8%AC%E2%80%8E`). If you want to use Arabic in `controller` or `method` names you have two options:

  1. In `application/config/routes.php` add url encoded route pointing to real route which could contain Arabic characters (as mentioned above, you can use UTF-8 characters in PHP identifiers). E.g.: `$route['welcome/%D8%A3'] = 'welcome/أ';` will enable user to go to `example.com/index.php/welcome/أ` which will call `أ` method (defined as `function أ() { ... }`) in `welcome` controller. Of course you can map arabic url encoded urls to normal ASCII names.
  2. [Extend](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) `system/core/Router.php` class so that `fetch_method` and `fetch_class` return url decoded names. I don't know what security implications are when you do this. Probably it is better to validate if input characters are indeed Arabic (i.e. you can check char ranges supplied [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode)). Example of modified `fetch_class`:

     ```
     function fetch_class()
     {
         return urldecode($this->class);
     }
     ```
- If you need to use Arabic characters in parameters of controller methods you just need to `urldecode` these parameters. E.g.:

  ```
  class Welcome extends CI_Controller
  {
      public function index($param)
      {
          $this->output->set_content_type("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
          echo urldecode($param);
      }
  }
  ```
- If you need to use these characters in query string it just works. E.g.

  ```
  class Welcome extends CI_Controller
  {
      public function index()
      {
          $this->output->set_content_type("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
          echo $this->input->get('arabic');
      }
  }
  ```

  Going to `example.com/index.php/welcome/index?arabic=ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي` will print out `ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي`.

Edit4: If you have `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'` then:

1. In config set `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\x{0600}-\x{06FF}';`
2. Extend `URI` class in `system/core/URI.php` so that in method `_filter_uri` line with `preg_match` is:

   ```
   if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-', '\{', '\}', '\\\\x'), array('-', '-', '{', '}', '\x'), preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars')))."]+$|ui", $str))
   ```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. I get php warning: "Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 32".

Comment: @user1324762 I'll debug this when I get home in the evening

Comment: @user1324762 I reread your question and I'm confused. Do you want to use arabic chars as controller or method names? I've managed to send arabic characters via `$_GET` (e.g. `www.example.com/index.php/welcome/index?arabic=ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي`) on CodeIgniter 2.1.3 on default settings. Do you have problem with sending via `$_GET` or you want to use arabic in controller/method names?

Comment: PS I've managed to use arabic chars in controller / method names without changing `permitted_uri_chars` with little hacking. Let me know if this is what you want and I'll edit my answer. Edit: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: I use php v 5.3.13. I want to pass it as parameter. I modified htaccess RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php/posts/show/$1 [L]. So for better illustration index.php/posts/show/ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي

Comment: And you get `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters` after using this kind of url?

Comment: I could use this URL without an error. I `urldecode`d parameter and I got arabic.

Comment: @user1324762 I've edited my answer. Check it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Tnx again for your help but in my case index.php/posts/show/ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي throws `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters` if I have `enable_query_strings` **FALSE**. I think that I will just leave permitted_uri_chars and validate it only when needed inside my methods.

Comment: @user1324762 I have `enable_query_strings` set to `FALSE` which is default value. Do you have default `permitted_uri_chars`? There should be percent sign `%` in there, i.e. I have `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`.

Comment: The same. Probably it is because of `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'`

Comment: @user1324762 Indeed. I managed to get it working on `PATH_INFO`. It looks like that the regexp was valid. 1. Set  `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\x{0600}-\x{06FF}';`. 2. Again we need to change the line with `preg_match` in `system/core/URI.php` in `_filter_uri` method. Try putting this code there: `if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-', '\{', '\}', '\\\\x'), array('-', '-', '{', '}', '\x'), preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars')))."]+$|ui", $str))` (`preg_quote` was escaping `\x`, `{` and `}`).

Comment: I'm very glad it works for you :). I've edited my answer (Edit4) so it includes `PATH_INFO` option.