# Problema returning a query with codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have this result when i make a query in CodeIgniter, i just started on it and make a connection in a database with mssql. Seems not want to run....

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Cód_cliente

Filename: contactos/index.php

Line Number: 2
```

My code in **Controller** is that:

```
<?php

class Contactos extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('conexion_bbdd');
    }
    public function index()
    {

        $data['contactos'] = $this->conexion_bbdd->get_empreses();
        $data['title'] = 'Conexi&oacute; a la base de dades per treure el llistat de clientes ';        


        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('contactos/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');


    }

}
```

My code on **Application**

```
<?php

class Conexion_bbdd extends CI_Model {
/* Funció que conecta amb la base de dades*/
    public function __construct()
    {
               $this->load->database();
    }
/* Funcio que carrega el llistat de empreses que hi han al despatx */
    public function get_empreses()
    {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM [DD\$Cliente]"); 
    return $query->row_array();


    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($contactos as $contactos_item): ?>
<p> <?php echo $contactos['C&oacute;d_cliente'] ?> </p></br>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Please, can you help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: mssql or mysql? It's unclear. Also, including special characters in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble.

Comment: maybe special characters problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362241/php-variable-function-class-names-using-special-characters

Comment: It's mssql @Strawberry.
I know it's a problema include this special characters but this Database is created. You know some codification from special caracters in query SQL? Thanks

Comment: The sentences is correct? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

here:

`<?php foreach ($contactos as $contactos_item): ?>
<p> <?php echo $contactos['C&oacute;d_cliente'] ?> </p></br>
<?php endforeach ?>`

try with $contact_item instead

`<?php foreach ($contactos as $contactos_item): ?>
<p> <?php echo $contactos_item['C&oacute;d_cliente'] ?> </p></br>
<?php endforeach ?>`

**also do not use c&ACUTE; as variables**

Comment: Thanks for que answer but doesn't run... The big problem is  think is the tables....

Answer (score 0):

You have one of two options:

**Declare Cód_cliente in your controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['contactos'] = $this->conexion_bbdd->get_empreses();
    $data['title'] = 'Conexi&oacute; a la base de dades per treure el llistat de clientes ';        

    $data['contactos']['Cód_cliente'] = 'something';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('contactos/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Check with `isset()` in your view**

```
<?php foreach ($contactos as $contactos_item): ?>
<p> <?php echo (isset($contactos['Cód_cliente']) ? $contactos['Cód_cliente'] : ''); ?> </p></br>
<?php endforeach ?>
```