# What are the valid characters in PHP variable, method, class, etc names?

Tags: php

What are the valid characters you can use in PHP names for variables, constants, functions, methods, classes, ...?

The manual has [some](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) [mentions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) of the regular expression `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`. When does this restriction apply and when does it not?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*` regex only applies when the name is used directly in some special syntactical element. Some examples:

```
$varName           // <-- varName needs to satisfy the regex
$foo->propertyName // <-- propertyName needs to satisfy the regex
class ClassName {} // <-- ClassName needs to satisfy the regex
                   //     and can't be a reserved keyword
```

Note that this regex is applied byte-per-byte, without consideration for encoding. That's why it also [allows many weird Unicode names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417180/exotic-names-for-methods-constants-variables-and-fields-bug-or-feature).

But the regex restricts *only* these "direct" uses of names. Through various dynamic features PHP provides it's possible to use virtually arbitrary names.

In general you **should make no assumptions** about which characters names in PHP can contain. To the most parts they are just arbitrary strings. Doing things like "validating if something is a valid class name" is just meaningless in PHP.

In the following I will provide examples of how you can create weird names for the different categories.

#### Variables

Variable names can be arbitrary strings:

```
${''} = 'foo';
echo ${''};      // foo
${"\0"} = 'bar';
echo ${"\0"};    // bar
```

#### Constants

Global constants can also be arbitrary strings:

```
define('', 'foo');
echo constant('');   // foo
define("\0", 'bar');
echo constant("\0"); // bar
```

There is no way to dynamically define class constants that I'm aware of, so those can not be arbitrary. Only way to create weird class constants seems to be via extension code.

#### Properties

Properties can not be the empty string and can not start with a NUL byte, but apart from this they are arbitrary:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{''} = 'foo';   // Fatal error: Cannot access empty property
$obj->{"\0"} = 'foo'; // Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0'
$obj->{'*'} = 'foo';
echo $obj->{'*'};     // foo
```

#### Methods

Method names are arbitrary and can be handled by `__call` magic:

```
class Test {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        echo "Called method \"$method\"";
    }
}

$obj = new Test;
$obj->{''}();    // Called method ""
$obj->{"\0"}();  // Called method "\0"
```

#### Classes

Arbitrary class names can be created using `class_alias` with the exception of the empty string:

```
class Test {}

class_alias('Test', '');
$className = '';
$obj = new $className; // Fatal error: Class '' not found

class_alias('Test', "\0");
$className = "\0";
$obj = new $className; // Works!
```

#### Functions

I'm not aware of a way to create arbitrary function names from userland, but there are still some occasions where internal code produces "weird" names:

```
var_dump(create_function('',''));
// string(9) "\0lambda_1"
```

Comment: A reference for this answer is http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Also the regex above is shown on that page as `^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$`

Answer (score 1):

[NikiC has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973357/what-are-the-valid-characters-in-php-variable-method-class-etc-names/17973365#17973365) all of them except functions. With variable functions you can have whatever name you want, though the syntax sucks.

```
${'=^^='}=function(){
   echo "Hello Kitty!";
};

${'=^^='}(); // Outputs "Hello Kitty!"
```

Comment: That's not a function name, it's a variable name. NikiC had them all all along.