# Why can I define a PHP function with a non-printing character?

Tags: php, non-printing-characters

I have always been under the impression that all php functions had to begin with `[a-zA-Z]`.

For instance, this would work:

```
function a1() {
  return "Something, because I'm written properly.";
}
```

... while this would not:

```
function 1a() {
  return "Nothing, because you'll encounter an error before this function ever runs.";
}
```

However the character that displays as a result of `rawurldecode('%E2%80%A9')`, when the document displaying it has a declared content type of UTF8, can also be used to define a function.

In a text editor that does not display hidden characters, it ultimately looks the the function has been defined as `function () {` which can then be executed by calling (what appears to be no more than) `();`

I can't paste the source code and have it still show up properly, so here are some screenshots. The first is a screenshot of what's been displayed in my browser, and the second is a screenshot of the actual source code as displayed inside my text editor (TextWrangler) with *Display hidden characters* turned on:

**Browser:**

---

[image]

---

**Source code:**

---

[image]

**My question: is this intentional? Should I be able to define functions/variables with non-printing characters and still have them work flawlessly? And if so, is it documented somewhere?**

I couldn't find any info about it, but I (obviously) don't know everything.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the valid characters in PHP variable, method, class, etc names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973357/what-are-the-valid-characters-in-php-variable-method-class-etc-names)

Comment: @AlmaDo I don't think it's a duplicate, as I cannot see a direct answer there to this question

Comment: Then you'd better to read that again. No offense, but there's no more clear and common answer than that, I think (because that includes common case and all limitations)

Comment: @AlmaDo that answer explains what is allowed and what is not. It does not explain if that is intentional or not, which was asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.

As explained in the [other answer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973357/what-are-the-valid-characters-in-php-variable-method-class-etc-names), regular expression is applied byte-per-byte, allowing "many weird Unicode names".

Doing it that way has some side-effects like you've seen. However, I can't imagine it was the original intent of people behind PHP, it would be just a direct consequence of the way they've implemented it.

Comment: I really suggest you to re-read NikiC's post. (Hint: '_Note that this regex is applied byte-per-byte, without consideration for encoding. That's why it also [also allows many weird Unicode names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417180/exotic-names-for-methods-constants-variables-and-fields-bug-or-feature)_' - as a quotation from there)

Comment: @AlmaDo I did. It explains well what are the current rules, but it doesn't really explain if the behaviour is *intended* or not.

Comment: I don't know how to comment that. If that is defined in PHP itself - then, _yes, that's intentional_. And that post clarifies that it is _allowed in PHP_ and also shows _why_ I don't know how to explain that then if it's unclear to you. Well, we all have our opinions - so you're free to think as you wish.

Comment: Every implementation bug there is in PHP would also be "defined in PHP itself". The regex is intended as it is documented, but byte-for-byte -comparison without regards for character set might just as well be just an implementation bug. But ok, we'll just disagree here then.