# php function and class with hyphen

Tags: php

i want to use hyphen instead of underscore but dreamweaver shows it as wrong for php functions and class

is there any way i can use hyphen

```
<?php
function sun_moon_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['sun_moon'] = array(
        'name'=>'sun_moon',
        'type'=>'community'
    );
    return $items;
}
?>
```

i want to make it sun-moon-menu

here is class which also does not accept -

```
<?php
class sun_moon {
    function index() {
    section_content('something');
    }
}
?>
```

why i want to use hyphen over underscores because this class becomes my websote direct link and hyphen is seo friendly overunderscore

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: not going to work....it's a mathematical operator

Comment: @Rizier123 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973357/what-are-the-valid-characters-in-php-variable-method-class-etc-names in this link i can see alternate way of defining class,. but can you please suggest how to do   same for functions

Comment: @RamRaider please help . i need some solution for class and functions  stackoverflow.com/questions/17973357/… in this link i can see alternate way of defining class,. but can you please suggest how to do same for functions

Comment: @nikic can u please help in changing class name as sun-moon instead of sun_moon      from <?php
class sun_moon {
    function index() {
    section_content('something');
    }
}
?>