# What are the valid characters in PHP namespace names?

Tags: php

What rules do my namespace names have to follow?

Comment: Closely related → http://stackoverflow.com/q/17973357/476

Answer (score 13):

> Variable names **follow the same rules as other labels** in PHP. A valid
> variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
> number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
> it would be expressed thus: `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

"Other labels" here does refer to namespaces among other things like class and function names.

Do note that PHP has no native understanding of encodings and treats such labels as mere byte arrays; most Unicode strings (read: UTF-8) will satisfy the above naïve regex:

```
// yup, works
namespace 漢字;
class 文字 {}
```

Comment: Noob question: I never used namespaces, but I remember seeing something like `namespace one\two`. Would that fit this rule?

Comment: @sidyll The backslash is a separator in hierarchical namespaces.

Comment: @sidyll The \ is the namespace separator, my question was about the components separated by the separator. Maybe I should make that clear in the question?

Comment: The namespace StillDreaming1\PurposefulPhp is giving me problems because of the 1...

Comment: Actually the namespace works fine, but it might be a problem with an autoloading bug in composer.

Comment: the regex supplied in the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) is **^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$** which has a different range. I believe \x7f matches the delete character.

Answer (score 3):

For those stumbling across this question: the following regex will validate a complete PHP namespace (not allowing a preceding or succeeding backslash).

```
^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff\\]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]$
```

When using PHP's `preg_match` the regex should be used like this:

```php
preg_match(
  '/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff\\\\]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]$/', 
  'Vendor\Package\Valid'
);
```

Comment: I am not so sure if consecutive backslashes are allowed. And I am pretty confident starting a namespace segment with number throws syntax error.
Howbout this one: `"/(^$)|(^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*(\\\\[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*)*$)/"` Also, \x80 as mentioned here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php