# Is it possible to use Emoji in PHP Namespaces?

Tags: php, utf-8, emoji

Hypothetically speaking, is it possible to use emoji characters in PHP namespaces? Are there any technical downsides?

Example:

```
<?php
/**
 * app/controllers/HomeController.php
 *
 * @package 
 */

namespace ;
use \Slim\Slim;
use \Requests;

class HomeController extends \\BaseController
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Comment: The documentation does not seem to oppose it really: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Except here where it states  _same rules as other labels_ http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Check also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417180/exotic-names-for-methods-constants-variables-and-fields-bug-or-feature